# Count overlapping occurences of a repeated string using grep/linux/bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, grep

I'm trying to count occurences of a repeated string. Eg.

```
echo 'joebobtomtomtomjoebobmike' | grep -o 'tomtom' | wc -l
```

This outputs 1, but obviously the string 'tomtom' fits twice here. How can I make it so it counts both occurences?

Thanks!

Comment: Done it! Thanks. Both your answer and potong answered my question efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this awk script

```
{
    count = 0
    $0 = tolower($0)
    while (length() > 0) {
        m = match($0, pattern)
        if (m == 0)
             break
        count++
        $0 = substr($0, m + 1)
    }
    print count
}
```

**Explanation**

We first convert the line to all lower case to ignore case. This script works by shortening the string after matching the pattern. It uses the function `match()` to find the position where the `pattern` is matched. If 
`m == 0`, that means no matches were found, so we can break from the loop. We increment `count` each iteration of the loop, then reset the `$0` string to the substring starting at index `m + 1`.

If you save this as a.awk, you can do

```
echo "joebobtomtomtomjoebobmike" | awk -v "pattern=tomtom" -f a.awk
```

And it will output `2`.

Comment: Thanks this works great (and relatively fast). Any way to make the match command ignore case?

Comment: You can first convert the `$0` to lower case using `tolower()`. Also note I've made the script a little more portable by using the variable `pattern`, which you pass in as an option to the script.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/(tom)\1/!d;:a;s//\n\1/;ta;s/\n//'| wc -l
```

The repeating pattern `tomtom` can be rewritten in regexp form as `(tom)\1` then replacing the first part of the repeating patten by a newline and looping until no more patterns are found will give a number of lines indicating the overlapping pattern. As the result is printed this must be taken into account and subtracted from the result i.e. the last (in this case the first) newline must be removed. Of course if there is no repeating pattern the result must be zero hence the first sed command.

Comment: This works! Any way to make sed ignore the newlines (without piping to tr to remove newlines)? Eg. echo -e 'tomtomtom\ntomtom' | sed -r '/(tom)\1/!d;:a;s//\n\1/;ta;s/\n//'| wc -l returns 3 but I want it to return 4

Comment: @Floris to remove newlines you could just slurp the whole file into memory by prepending the existing command with `:b;$!{N;bb};s/\n//g;`

Answer (score 1):

You could just walk the length of the string and see if the substring at the current location is the desired text:

```
string=joebobtomtomtomjoebobmiketomtomtom
match=tomtom
for ((i=0; i <= ${#string} - ${#match}; i++)); do
    [[ ${string:i:${#match}} == $match ]] && ((count++))
done
echo $count   # => 4
```